# How to enable "Next" or "Finish" button in Android Studio when adding Android library as a dependency

Tags: android

I'm following the [instructions on Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html) to import a AAR file as a module. I'm using the instructions under "Add your library as a dependency." I browse to select my .aar file, but the 'Next' and 'Finish' buttons are disabled. I don't see any error messages. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

[image]

I select the .aar file by browsing for it, so the path is correct.

[image: 'Next' and 'Finish' buttons are disabled]

Buttons are disabled, although there are no error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out right after posting it. My project gradle sync errors, so I had to fix those first before I was allowed to import the project. As soon as I fixed that and synced I was able to import the project.

Thanks.

Comment: What if there is no gradle sync error?

Comment: @wEight sorry, I do not know. I haven't encountered this without a gradle sync error.

Comment: Well, my solution was copying the whole src folder to my project and implement necessary dependencies.

Comment: The necessary dependencies are ```implementation project(':projectname')``` in ```build.gradle (:app)``` and ```include ':app', ..., ':projectname'``` in ```settings.gradle```

Comment: i am just trying to install adroid studio and ... bith finish and next are not active!